# Number of positive integers between 1 and 2300 inclusive that are relatively prime to 700.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of positive integers between 1 and 2300 inclusive that are relatively prime to 700.

I have no idea how to approach this question, honestly.

Comment: If two numbers are not relatively prime, that means they share a prime factor. What prime factors would that be in the case of $700$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:You should apply [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

---

Not that $700 = 2^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7$, so $n$ is **not** relatively prime with 700, if and only if $7 \mid n \vee 5 \mid n \vee 2 \mid n$.

Let

$$ A = \lbrace x\in \mathbb{N}^{+}: x \leq 2300 \wedge 2 \mid x  \rbrace\\
B = \lbrace x\in \mathbb{N}^{+}: x \leq 2300 \wedge 5 \mid x  \rbrace\\
C = \lbrace x\in \mathbb{N}^{+}: x \leq 2300 \wedge 7 \mid x  \rbrace
$$

Number of numbers, which are **not** coprime with 700 in this rage is $|A \cup B \cup C|$, from inclusion–exclusion principle we obtain solution.

$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$$

Its easy to notice $|A| = \lfloor \frac{2300}{2}\rfloor, |B| = \lfloor \frac{2300}{5}\rfloor, |C| = \lfloor \frac{2300}{7}\rfloor$.

$$\begin{split}
|A \cap B| &= \left|\lbrace x \in \mathbb{N}^{+}: x \leq 2300 \wedge 2 \mid x \wedge 5 \mid x\rbrace \right | = \left\lfloor\frac{2300}{2\cdot 5}\right\rfloor\\
|A \cap C| &=  \left\lfloor\frac{2300}{2\cdot 7}\right\rfloor\\
\end{split}$$

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: 1) $700$ is divisible by $2$, $5$ and $7$.

2) [Inclusion-Exclusion principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 2):

First note that $700 = 2^2 5^27$.

A number is relatively prime to $700$ if none of $\{2,5,7\}$ divide it.
So what we can do is consider the $2300$ numbers in the range $[1,2300]$
and subtract the number multples of $2, 5, $ and $7$ in that range. 
But then we have subtracted too many things (for instance we have removed the number $10$ twice) so we have to add back in the number of multiples of pairs of  these three primes, i.e. add the number of multiples of $10$, $14$, and $35$ less than $2300$ back in.

But then we have to subtract out the number of multiples of three of these primes ... etc.